# Search keys in the dictionary and return both key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary like `{'Mike':'98','Tom':'57'}`. How could I do search based on names which is the key in this case and return both key and value?

I have roughly heard about create a turple of dict so that dictionary become `{"Name":"Mike","Mark":"98"},{"Name":"Tom","Mark":"47"}}`. So one can do:

```
for a in dict:
   if a["Name"] == ""
```

However I don't know how to do that to my existing dictionary as well.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Where in the above code would you return? What is the point of the `if` check here?

Comment: What keys are you searching for?

Comment: i am searching for names so for the if loop it is if a["Name"] = "Mike", if i want to search for Mike?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think i figured out in the end. I still used dictionary and it looks like this.

```
b = []
for name,mark in Marks.items():
   if name== search_name:
       b.append(name)
       b.append(mark)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
your_dictionary = {'Mike': '98', 'Tom': '57'}
search_key = 'Mike'

if search_key in your_dictionary:
    print(search_key, your_dictionary[search_key]
```

The `if` statement checks that the key is in the dictionary and then you get the value using the key.

Dictionaries are good for look-ups so you don’t have to go through the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

```py
a={'Mike':'98','Tom':'57'}
search='Tom'
for key, value in a.items():
    if key == search:   print(key, value)
```

I believe what you're asking is to print a key and value when the key matches a value in a loop?

I'm pretty confused, not really sure what you're asking but the above would search the dictionary for the key 'Tom' then print the key and value of it.

Answer (score -1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
data = {'Mike':'98','Tom':'57'}
result = [{'name': k, 'mark': v} for k, v in data.items()]
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'Mike', 'mark': '98'}, {'name': 'Tom', 'mark': '57'}]
```